# Two *different* mount points having the *same* absolute path (bind-mount problem)

Tags: linux, mount, unmounting, bind-mount

### Scenario

- a NFS share is mounted on `/mnt/temp/dir` (and other shares are mounted in subdirectories),
- I `umount` everything there but supposedly, it doesn't work well (maybe I start with `umount /mnt/temp/dir` instead of umounting "nested" shares like `/mnt/temp/dir/subdir*` first),
- I do `mount -o bind /data/temp /mnt/temp`,
- I do `mount /mnt/temp/dir`,
- I do `mount /mnt/temp/dir/subdir1`... and it works well.

Note: `/mnt/temp` is initially hosted on the root (`/`) filesystem `/dev/sda6`, and `/data` is another filesystem from `/dev/sda8`.

### Problem

I cannot delete the `/mnt/temp/dir` directory on the root filesystem:

```
# mount -o bind / /test/root
# rmdir /test/root/mnt/temp/dir
rmdir: failed to remove `dir': Device or resource busy
```

### Some explanation

`/mnt/temp/dir` is mounted ***twice***, probably once on the root fs, and once on the `/data` fs.

Here is `cat /proc/mounts`:

```
nfsserver:/some/share/ /mnt/temp/dir nfs rw,relatime(...) 0 0
nfsserver:/some/share/ /mnt/temp/dir nfs rw,relatime,(...) 0 0
```

More interesting, here is `cat /proc/1/mountinfo`:

```
29 20 0:18 / /mnt/temp/dir rw,relatime - nfs nfsserver:/some/share/ rw,(...)
33 31 0:18 / /mnt/temp/dir rw,relatime - nfs nfsserver:/some/share/ rw,(...)
```

See, the two numbers at the beginning are *different*.

[Kernel doc says](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt?id=v2.6.39#n1493) for these two fields:

```
(1) mount ID:  unique identifier of the mount (may be reused after umount)
(2) parent ID:  ID of parent (or of self for the top of the mount tree)
```

They also have different parents 20 and 31 (root fs and `/data` fs), see:

```
20 1 8:6 / / rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda6 rw,(...)
31 20 8:8 /temp /mnt/temp rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda8 rw,(...)
```

If I try to `umount /mnt/temp/dir`, I get 2 error messages:

```
umount.nfs: /mnt/temp/dir: device is busy
umount.nfs: /mnt/temp/dir: device is busy
```

## Question

**How can I `umount` the "bad" one (mount ID 29)?**

Even the `umount(2)` system call takes a path for argument, and not a "mount ID".

Comment: Please provide the output of `lsof /mnt/temp/dir `

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but it'll at least bypass the “device is busy” problem.

Move one the mount point to a different location. That way, there won't be any more confusion between the two mount points.

```
mkdir /foo
mount --move /mnt/temp/dir /foo
```

Comment: Instead of using the filesystem path, `umount /mnt/temp/dir` use the device path `umount nfsserver:/some/share/`. If both mounts _are_ the same share, then mount may have to decide, arbitrarily, which one to unmount, but no matter which one it does, you'll be out of the problem and can clean it up from there.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver This does not aid success, in unmounting an nfs mount which is underneath another mount.  `/sbin/umount` uses the `umount2()` system call which simply takes a path.  It may change the effect however.  I haven't tested for nfs, but `/sbin/umount` appears able to detect when you're trying to do the impossible, and will simply print `invalid argument`.

Comment: I tested what *Gilles* suggests: `--move` fails with an error in my use case ("cannot move a mount residing under a shared mount" if I remember well). Even though, I doubt it could work if the mount was private. I also tested `umount nfsserver:/some/share/` as *Gypsy Spellweaver* suggests and it fails as well. Not surprinsing for me because the `umount(2)` syscall takes a **target** for argument, and I guess the `umount(8)` utility only translates the source to a target using info provided by the system, then making the very same (failing) syscall.